# Can't resize gimp toolbox below certain width on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: window, gimp

I used to be able to resize the left toolbox in a single-window mode just a few weeks ago. But since I reinstalled Ubuntu. I can no longer change the size below 6 columns.

This only happens in single-window mode. I don't know what changed since the last install. I tried few different versions of gimp, all of them have the same problem.

Comment: Screenshot, please.

Comment: Seems to depend on the tabs we add to the lower section of the toolbox, for instance if I add gradient-tab, I am limited to five columns in single-window mode, if I add the layer-tab I am limited to 6 columns. With only the tool-option-tab I am limited to three columns minimum. You can drag other tabs to the dock on the right side of the screen which is a bit wider by default.

Comment: That's it @mook765 I had a tab with colours open which didn't let me make it smaller. Would be great if you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal size of the Gimp-toolbox is different in single-window-mode and depends on the tabs added to the lower section of the toolbox. With only the tool-options-tab the minimal size is three columns.

If you add other tabs, the minimal size will increase, for instance adding the gradient-tab limits the minimal size to 5 columns, adding the layer-tab increase the minimal size to 6 columns.

We can add these tabs to the dock on the right side of the window which is a bit wider then the toolbox by default. Already to the toolbox added tabs can simply be dragged to the other dock.